# Open a completely new window with JavaScript without replacing the contents of the previous window

Tags: javascript, window, new-operator

I have a page with several links that open a separate window with varying content. My goal is to open a window for each and every such link using JavaScript. My problem is as follows:

let's assume:
- i have two links on the page, lnkDoWorkOne and lnkDoWorkTwo
- lnkDoWorkOne opens a window with url = WorkOne.aspx which in turn does some work upon loading
- lnkDoWorkTwo opens a window with url = WorkTwo.aspx which also does some work

In my present solution when I click lnkDoWorkOne then a new window opens with WorkOne.aspx and works just fine. Then when I click lnkDoWorkTwo, then there's no new window at all but the contents of the previously opened window are simply replaced by WorkTwo.aspx. I need to have BOTH windows open with WorkOne.aspx and WorkTwo.aspx so that the user can view the contents in parallel.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you giving the same window name to the both `window.open` calls? If so, change the name of the window and you should get two separate windows.

```
window.open('WorkOne.aspx', 'window1');
...
window.open('WorkTwo.aspx', 'window2');
```

Answer (score 0):

window.open(url , 'related_url');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).